# How do I create a SWIG descriptor for an typedef?

Tags: swig

I'm using SWIG 2.0.  I have a C++ smart pointer class which I'd like to avoid exposing in my target language (in this case Python).  A few typemaps should allow me to do this.  Here's my first attempt at an "out" typemap for example:

```
%typemap(out) smart_ptr
%{
    // Get the object from the internal pointer.
    if ($1.get() == NULL)
        $result = Py_None;
    else
        $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj($1.get(), $descriptor($1_type::target_type),
            0);
%}
```

Using this typemap, if it worked, I should be able to expose `smart_ptr< Foo > getAFoo();` as a function returning a `Foo`, not a `SmartPtrFoo`.

The problem is that SWIG generates the descriptor as "*swigt*__1_type__target_type" instead of expanding `smart_ptr< T >::target_type` to `Foo` to get, for example, "*swigt*_Foo".

I could do something like this:

```
#define SMART_PTR_TYPEMAPS(VALUE_TYPE)

%typemap(out) smart_ptr< VALUE_TYPE >
%{
    // Get the object from the internal pointer.
    if ($1.get() == NULL)
        $result = Py_None;
    else
        $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj($1.get(), $descriptor(VALUE_TYPE),
            0);
%}

#enddef
```

but this forces me to expand a macro for every type for which I use a smart_ptr.  I'd rather let the SWIG typemap search mechanism do the work.

Is there a way to generate a descriptor for an expanded typedef?

Comment: Curious to know why the techniques from [section 6.24 of SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_smart_pointers) don't work for you; would obviate need for typemap.

Comment: @Schollii, I'm following that section currently, but I wanted to see if I could eliminate the extra types by the smart pointer.  Also, my smart pointer is a reference counting pointer, so it really isn't needed if I can use `%feature("ref")`.  Basically, I'm experimenting a bit.

Comment: This is all opaque in target language as you can hide all methods of the smart pointer and just have those of the underlying object, what are you worried about?